# Problem when requiring module in ionic framework

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my project (using the ionic-framework 3) I have used following statement to require the dialogflow module:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
```

On compilation it's throwing the following error:

> cannot find name 'require'.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `import * as dialogflow from 'dialogflow';`?

Comment: I haven't imported that. Is it the same way I have to write as you have written?

Answer (score 0):

Add types to tsconfig.json

```
"types": [
    "node"
],
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
]
```